# Правильная работа с torrentlibrary C#

Tags: c#, парсер, torrent

Здравствуйте. Скачал вот [эту](https://torrentlibrary.codeplex.com) библиотеку. Распаковал ее, добавил в проект, попутно создав папки такие же, как и в самой библиотеке и заполнил эти папки файлами из соответствующих папок в библиотеке (смотреть изображение). В области using подключил эту библиотеку так:

```
using WDS.Bencode;
```

Но при любой попытке открыть торрент-файл на редактирование он сыплет ошибка, вроде "A bencoded file should only contain exactly one root element. 23 tokens were found." или же, например, "Error while parsing string length". Может кто объяснить, что я делаю не так? Ну или подсказать другие пути редактирования торрент-файла.
Открываю так:

```
BencodeElement fileDom = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\file.torrent").ToBencodeElement();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты добавил в проект исходники либы=>Ты можешь увидеть точное место в методе расширителе, что не понравилось твоей либе. Как вариант, ты используешь либу 2010 года=>за все это время формат мог притерпеть изменения.